# CSS - sticky grid header

Tags: html, css, position, css-grid, sticky

I'm trying to create a sticky header from a group of cells in a grid.

This is the code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  display: contents;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.header > .cell {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<div class="header">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make the red cells "stick"?
Is it the right approach for such a problem or should I separate the header to be a different component?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, put `sticky` to the cells, not the `header`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  display: contents;
}
.header > .cell {
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<div class="header">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are a god send!

Comment: How to make the scrollbar to be started below header (red in the example) cells?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the header div and give the divs that were previously inside it the appropriate position.

`display:contents` merely makes the container div act as though it were not there so the wrapper is unnecessary.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell header"></div>
  <div class="cell header"></div>
  <div class="cell header"></div>
  <div class="cell header"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```